# How to properly redirect an http URL to a new https URL in WordPress on IIS8

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite, iis

I'm running WordPress on IIS8 and I'm having some 301 redirect issues. I have URL Rewrite enabled and it is working properly.

I'm using the Simple 301 Redirects plugin in WordPress, which works fine if I am redirecting an https URL to a different https URL. If I try to redirect an old http URL to its new (and differently named) https counterpart, however, I get a 404 error.

For example:

http://www.domain.com/MIG-Support => https://www.domain.com/dynamics-gp/dynamics-gp-support/

How do I resolve this? I do have access to the config file.

Thanks in advance!

Cynthia

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it manually (without a plugin) in your .htaccess?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^old-url/(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/new-URL$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: IIS doesn't use htaccess that I am aware of.

Comment: You could try the URL rewire extension for IIS: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, URL rewrite is already installed. https to https redirects work fine. It's http to https with a different URL structure that does not work.